# [CALayer isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, zxing

I am using zxing library to scan barcodes. Whenever i scan wrong barcode,a mail composer will open a mail saying that wrong barcode scanned. When we dismmiss the mail composer,we can scan again . However, when I dismiss the mail composer,my app gets crashed saying "[CALayer isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance"

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));// app crashed at this line
}
}
```

Here is what I have

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];

 [self.capture.layer removeFromSuperlayer];

   [self.view.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
   self.view = nil;
    self.capture=nil;

}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

self.capture.delegate = self;
self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
_scanRectView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
_scanRectView.layer.borderWidth = 2;


CGAffineTransform captureSizeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(320 / self.view.frame.size.width, 480 / self.view.frame.size.height);
self.capture.scanRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.scanRectView.frame, captureSizeTransform);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//initialising the zxing library to start the camera
self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;


self.capture.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];



[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scanRectView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.decodedLabel];


}
```

Kindly tell me,where am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your viewDidDisappear method is wrong

it will be

```
   -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.capture.layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.capture=nil;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //initialising the zxing library to start the camera
    self.capture = [[ZXCapture alloc] init];
    self.capture.camera = self.capture.back;


    self.capture.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
    self.capture.rotation = 90.0f;

    self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.capture.layer];



    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scanRectView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.decodedLabel];


    self.capture.delegate = self;
    self.capture.layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _scanRectView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    _scanRectView.layer.borderWidth = 2;


    CGAffineTransform captureSizeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(320 / self.view.frame.size.width, 480 / self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.capture.scanRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.scanRectView.frame, captureSizeTransform);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: i removed those lines from the view did disappear,the apps not crashing now. But ,my app supposed to open the camera layer and start scanning,but the layer is freezed....the code in view did load is not getting called i guess!!!

Comment: once we dismmiss the mail composer,the camera layer should be added to the view ,but here it is not happening

Comment: ok T_77, Please tell me which propery you are using for ZXCapture* capture.

Comment: So, You got crash when you come back to camera layer view, right?

Comment: it is not crashing. I can move to other tabs,and come back to this scanning tab. But the view is freezed.

Comment: if possible can you team view for a moment?

Comment: Ok, I got the problem, I will edit my answer soon. :)

Comment: Actually i put those lines in view did disappear because,the camera layer is still scanning even though i go to another view.

Comment: No, right now not possible. I have to go on job. I will free after 10 hours.